# Two old papers, or an old journal, or both

Tags: logic, reference-request, propositional-calculus

I am searching two Carew Meredith’s papers ***Single axioms for the systems (C, N), (C, 0) and (A, N) of the two-valued propositional calculus*** and ***A single axiom of positive logic***. The papers were published on the ***Journal of Computing System*** in 1954 and has been citied many times in other papers and webpages. However, I can’t find the papers or even the journal in libraries  and Internet. Would you mind tell me where can I get them all ?

References :

(1)
C. Meredith, Single axioms for the systems (C, N), (C, 0) and (A, N) of the two-valued propositional calculus, Journal of Computing Systems, pp. 155–164, 1954.

(2)
C. Meredith, A single axiom of positive logic, Journal of Computing Systems, p. 169–170, 1954.

Comment: Have you tried asking a library to get them for you on interlibrary loan?

Comment: The first paper seems to be available at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274185557_Meredith_Carew_A_Single_axioms_for_the_systems_C_N_C_O_and_A_N_of_the_two-valued_propositional_calculus_The_journal_of_computing_systems_vol_1_no_3_1953_pp_155-164 but I don't know what you have to do to get it from them.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The librarian says there is no information about the journal in their database. I search in internet and cannot find anything about the journal, too. It seems that the journal may stop publication.

Comment: Worldcat (https://www.worldcat.org/title/journal-of-computing-systems/oclc/297360054&referer=brief_results) knows of 25 libraries with this journal.  Most are in America, three in Europe, one in Australia, one in New Zealand.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is the review of the first paper written by Alonzo Church.

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you. However, I can’t borrow the Journal as I am living in Asia and I graduated from university for a long time.